# Only 2 out of 100 child processes getting CPU in a multiprocessed program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing, fork

**PROBLEM FACED:**

I have a program which connects to a server and send a hash for lookup and return some sort of respose.

In my current setup, i have a base system which sends requests to Server each of 1 in number.
So in order to do multiple lookup's i used multiprocessing in python to lauch 100 processes which inturn do the lookup work.When after sometime when i want to know how my child processes are behaving did a CPU and Memory Stats,which showed a interesting behaviour only 2 out of 100 child's are getting CPU and Memory and rest are always 0.0.

Any one with idea whats happening? Is something wrong with my implementation.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
def start_scan(files):
        """
        Multiprocessing scanner
        """
        try:
                for filedata in files:
                        start = time.time()
                        res = scan(os.path.join('/home/something/test/'+ filedata))
                        with open('result_clean.csv' , 'a') as f:
                                data_in_file = "Result {} for file {}".format(str(res),filedata)
                                f.write(data_in_file)
                                f.write('\n')

                        end = time.time()
                        logger.info('File {} took {} for processing'.format(filedata,end-start))
        except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Error in scanning files {}'.format(str(e)))

def clean_(self,worker=100):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=worker)
    start = time.time()
    input_files = []
    file_path = self.folder_clean_scan
    input_files.append(os.listdir(file_path))
    targetLists = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, 1):
            if (i < ( len(input_files) % 1)):
            # This one gets a remainder
                    targetLists.append(input_files[count:(count + 1 + ( len(input_files) / 1))])
                    count += 1 + ( len(input_files) / 1)
            else:
            # No remainder
                    targetLists.append(input_files[count:(count + ( len(input_files) / 1))])
                    count += len(input_files) / 1
    #print targetLists[0]
    results = [ pool.apply_async(start_scan,
            args=(x)) \
            for x in targetLists ]

    try:

            output = [ p.get() for p in results ]
            print output
    except:
            traceback.print_exc()
    end = time.time()
    print end -start
```

**MEMORY STATS INFO**

```
ps -ax -o %cpu,%mem,cmd | grep app
 0.8  0.0 python app.py
 3.3  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
 0.0  0.0 python app.py
```

Comment: Just a guess, but would `with open('result_clean.csv' , 'a') as f:` be blocking since all process is trying to append to it?

Comment: Is there any alternative rather than appending to file ?

Comment: I would confirm that's indeed the problem by writing to a different file for each process first. If that's really the case, then maybe a) have the result be transported back to the main process in-memory (if it's relatively small) b) keep writing to different files and aggregate at a later stage?